# Capacitor and resistors at t=0 and t after long time

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I’m pretty sure my answer is wrong because I forgot to include the capacitor in the calculation and I don't know how I'm supposed to do that.

Find the current for each resistor and in the capacitor at t=0 and after a long time.

[image]

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fERjgk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$
\mathrm{I_1} = \mathrm{I_2} + \mathrm{I_3}
\$

\$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{R_{eq2,3}} &= {\left(\frac{1}{\mathrm{R_2}}+\frac{1}{\mathrm{R_3}}\right)}^{\displaystyle-1}\\
&= {\left(\frac{1}{3300}+\frac{1}{5000}\right)}^{\displaystyle-1}\\
&= 1987.95\Omega
\end{aligned}
\$

\$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{R_{eq}} &= \mathrm{R_1} + \mathrm{R_{eq2,3}}\\
&= 1000 + 1987.95\\
&= 2987.95 \Omega
\end{aligned}
\$

\$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{I_1} &= \frac{12}{2987.95}\\
&= 4\!\times\!10^{-3} \mathrm{A}
\end{aligned}
\$

\$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta\mathrm{V} &= \mathrm{I_1} \cdot \mathrm{R_1}\\
&= 4\!\times\!10^{-3} \cdot 1000\\
&= 4 \mathrm{V}
\end{aligned}
\$

\$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{I_2} &= \frac{8}{3300}\\
&= 2.42\!\times\!10^{-3}\mathrm{A}
\end{aligned}
\$

\$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{I_3} &= \mathrm{I_1} - \mathrm{I_2}\\
&= 1.58\!\times\!10^{-3}\mathrm{A}
\end{aligned}
\$

Comment: Can you transcribe your work and rotate the image to be the right way up?

Comment: The voltage on capacitor cannot change instantaneously.

Comment: Please redraw your circuit using the schematic tool and label each component.  This site also uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can write maths so it is easy to read.

Comment: Also for \$ t = 0 \$ do you mean \$ t = 0^- \$, The switch has been open for a long time or \$ t=0^+ \$ the instant the swich has been closed?

Comment: @WarrenHill Calculating current/voltages for t=0-epsilon does not make much sense, since it already says "the capacitor [is] initially uncharged"; so with the switch open, there's initially 0V and 0A everywhere.

Comment: @JimmyB I disagree, every component including the wire and voltage source in the circuit is assumed ideal, no ESL, EPC, ESR, EPR, et cetera. So even with switch opened at t=0 there will be 12V across the voltage source terminal.

Comment: @Unknown123 Yes, of course. But the question asks for voltages and currents of the R's and the C, which, with switch open and C uncharged, you don't have to "calculate" for because it's (obviously?) 0.

Comment: @JimmyB what about when the switch is closed

Answer (score 1):

At `t=0`, the capacitor is completely discharged and has 0V across it.

At `t=infinity`, the capacitor is fully charged. How much current will flow into/through the capacitor then? What voltage drop will occur due to that current across the 3.3k resistor?

Look at the charge curve of a capacitor, e.g. [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html):

[image]

It also has the values for `t=0` and `t->infinity`.

You can see that for long `t` the charge and the voltage approach 100% while the current goes towards 0. Theoretically, the capacitor will only ever be exactly 100% charged after an infinite amount of time, but it will be *very* close to 100% (99.9999...%) after a small multiple of the R*C time constant. This can be seen from the `1-exp(-t/...)` term, which approaches 1 (100%) exponentially over `t`.

Comment: So at t=0 are my calculations correct? I highly doubt that tho. I really hope u can understand the hand writing

Comment: Not sure which is R1, R2 or R3, but yes, at t=0 you have one resistor (R1?) in series with the two other resistors in parallel (R2||R3?).

Comment: 1kohm is R1, 3.3kohm is R2 and 5kohm is R3 and thanks for your confirmation

Comment: Also how am i suppose to find the current for each resistor and the capacitor at t long time or infinite

Comment: "At t=infinity, the capacitor is fully charged."

Comment: I get it but how to prove it in calculations

Comment: You don't prove that. You understand that at t=infinity the capacitor is fully charged, which implies that ..., and take that as the needed additional information to calculate currents at t=infinity.

Comment: Just answer my question: "the capacitor is fully charged. How much current will flow into/through the capacitor then?" :)

Comment: If you need to prove what happens at t-\$\inf\$ then you take the limit of the voltage across the capacitor as t approaches infinity. OR just put in a very large number which is close to infinity, the value will asymptotically approach the final value with increasingly large numbers.

Comment: @JimmyB I don’t know ☹️‍♂️

Comment: @Abdullah What is your current background of studies right now? Have you studied limit and differential equation in calculus? Do you understand the concept of transient and steady-state condition? Your question above for \$\mathrm{t}=0\$ towards \$\mathrm{t}=\inf\$ needs differential equation to solve it completely, to prove it you need the concept of limits.

Comment: @Unknown123 im taking calculus 1 and physics 2 but this is physics lab 2. In my uni physics 2 has barely anything to do with physics lab 2. So basically I’ve no idea how im so suppose to use limit t->infinity to solve this question, i dont know how to start. I’ll try to get the doc to explain it to me but he probably won’t cuz we just took this experiment today and this is H.W  thx for the help tho i get what you are trying to say i just dont know how to put it in equations that’s all

Comment: @Abdullah Ideally you have to take a headstart to understand every prerequisite lab material completely as much as you can before you do practicum in the lab itself including practical and ideal condition. Brace yourself and YOLO are not acceptable in this case, wrong usage of the capacitor, could lead to harmful situations. Learn is all your need, read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264180/deriving-the-formula-from-scratch-for-charging-a-capacitor). Please make progress and come back to edit/update your question if you stuck again.

Comment: @Abdullah "The capacitor is fully charged" implies that it does not charge further. This means that there's no more charge going into/out of it, i.e. the current through the capacitor is 0A. Can you solve the question with this information?

Answer (score 0):

At t=0 the capacitor has 0V (zero voltage) across it.  At that instant t=0 it will act like a short circuit.  That allows you to solve for the currents using the circuit shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO1TOr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At t=inf the capacitor is fully charged has 0A (zero current) through it. So at t=inf it behaves like an open circuit.  Solve for currents per circuit below.  Obviously I_R3 = 0.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBKCgU.png)</sup>

Comment: I think it is very misleading to say that the capacitor is a short circuit at t=0. Yes, the voltage across the capacitor is zero but **not** because the capacitor is a short circuit. A capacitor is **always** an open circuit at dc.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Since in an ideal capacitor, the \$\mathrm{ESR} = 0\$. I think it's because the difference in steady-state and transient perspective point of view. I think if scorpdaddy edited this answer by provide more details it would be better. Perhaps its also the reason of why the downvote.

Comment: @Unknown123 It really has nothing to do with ESR. Since \$i_C = C\,dV/dt\$ it must be true that \$i_C = 0\$ when \$dV/dt = 0\$...in other words, at dc. So, what we know for certain is that the current through a capacitor must be zero at dc, which means that a capacitor looks like an **open circuit** at dc. If the voltage across the capacitor happens to also be zero then that is just a coincidence, it doesn't imply a short circuit.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I really like the precision of your statement wording here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes, I agree it doesn't imply a short circuit, it only **acts** or **looks** like short circuit at \$\mathrm{t}=0\$ as in this case it would be \$\displaystyle \frac{d\mathrm{V_c(t)}}{dt} = \frac{\mathrm{V_{th}}}{\mathrm{R_{th}C}}\cdot e^{\displaystyle\left(-\frac{\mathrm{t}}{\mathrm{R_{th}C}}\right)}\$, thus at \$\mathrm{t}=0 \implies \displaystyle \frac{d\mathrm{V_c(0)}}{dt} = \frac{\mathrm{V_{th}}}{\mathrm{R_{th}C}} \implies \mathrm{I_c(0)} = \frac{\mathrm{V_{th}}}{\mathrm{R_{th}}}\$

Comment: @Unknown123 At t=0+ we no longer have a dc situation, we have a transient situation. The capacitor **does not** act like a short circuit in that instant. Because the capacitor voltage must be continuous, the capacitor acts like an **ideal voltage source** with a value equal to \$v_C(0-)\$. It is only a **coincidence** that in this case that voltage is zero...that does not mean that the capacitor acts like a short circuit. If you put that in your head you will struggle when \$v_C(0-) \ne 0\$ so you should use the correct concepts from the start.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes you're right, since it's stated that \$v_C(0-) = 0\$, not as a general, that's why I told earlier that this answer could be improved by providing more details.

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable to say that at t=0 the capacitor "looks/acts like" a short circuit in this case. This is specifically what the question aims at, the understanding that at t=0 the cap has 0V and max. current and at t=infiniy the cap has 0A.

Comment: The poster didn't ask if a 0V capacitor was a short circuit.  They asked how to calculate the currents in the circuit.  The approximations in the diagrams allow the poster to get the correct currents.  And hopefully shows them how to determine the answer to similar questions in the future.  Without getting bogged down in the existential nature of a capacitor at 0V.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Pardon, I mention you in case JimmyB or scorpdaddy comments didn't get into your inbox.

Comment: @Unknown123 I've seen how this goes. Some student reads this answer "At that instant t=0 it will act like a short circuit." Full stop, no "in this case", no qualifiers. They apply that mistaken "rule" to every transient analysis and it takes forever for them to unlearn it.